# FatalExecutionEngineError on InitializeComponent when using IValueConverter

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, ivalueconverter, winrt-xaml

I have a list of items in a listbox. When the selected item changes, it's details are displayed: I set the `DataContext` of a `Grid` to that object, and insert a specific UserControl that displays the details.
I am getting a `FatalExecutionEngineError` on the InitializeComponent() of these User Controls.

```
The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x6d8c104e, on thread 0xcf4. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
```

The error goes away when I remove bindings that use Value Converts. Some converters seem to not cause the exception... Also the error shows up only when I create new instances of the User Controls for each item to be displayed, but not when re-using the same User Controls that are creating at app start-up.
Are there any know issues with the IValueConverter ? If so should I not use them in my application ? Where could I find a list of bugs for the Consumer Preview so I don't waste my time trying to find work-arounds for bugs that will be fixed in later releases ?

Comment: An `FatalExecutionEngineError` should pretty much never happen. The CLR crashed. Can you post a small reproducible example?

Comment: You are using a beta version of VS and a preview version of Windows.  So your program falling over on nasty memory corruption problems is to be expected.  You can post bugs at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @vcsjones I don't know how I could post a small example, the app gets it's info from a wcf service hosted on azure, which is then saved locally, each item sorted into a category etc. I'll try posting some code and xaml in the proximity of where the exceptions gets thrown.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a list of bugs but this one has caused many people many hours if not days of frustration as you can see here and on the Microsoft forums.  Avoid custom converters until we get a new release in June.  Even if you think you have a working converter, you probably don't and your app will still crash at seemingly random times.  Sucks, but that's what betas are for I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround that seemed to make these more stable for me was to move the converter resource () and the thing that uses it (e.g. a DataTemplate) from a central application-wide ResourceDictionary to an individual Page's Resource section.

Answer (score 0):

change processor in properties from 86x to 64x

Answer (score 0):

I had put all my resources in one common project. This was what was causing the issue for me. I copied the resources to each individual project and problem solved.1

Thanks a lot for this answer. I spend 6 hours on this already until i stumbled on this post.!!!whew.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up), you will be able to vote up questions and answers that you found helpful.